# registerForPreviewing in a tableview cell, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, 3dtouch

I'm trying to add this to a table view cell but because it is awake from nib and not view did load it won't allow it.

```
if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available
    {
        registerForPreviewing(with: self as! UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate, sourceView: collectionView)
    }
    else
    {
        print("3D Touch Not Available")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that is a delegate, registerForPreviewing initialize the delegate's instance. You can do it in the dequeue:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BBVAIntranet_Somos_Comedores_Menu_Dia_CollectionViewCell.identifier,
                                                     for: indexPath) as? BBVAIntranet_Somos_Comedores_Menu_Dia_CollectionViewCell {

        print("item: \(indexPath.item)")            
        self.refrescar_menuDia_delegate = cell
        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
            registerForPreviewing(with: cell, sourceView: cell.tableView)
        }
        self.refrescar_menuDia_delegate?.refrescar_menu_dia_collectioncell_delegate(menu: self.menus[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```